# regex replace works on grunt but not gulp

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

I am trying to remove comments from js.

I have tried gulp-strip-comments. But it does not remove block comments like

```
/*! jQuery UI - v1.11.4 - 2015-03-11
* http://jqueryui.com */
```

So i wrote a regex to replace it. It will replace all chars in between `/*` and `*/`

my regex `/\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\//g` . This regex works fine in grunt but not working with gulp.

Any suggestion or is there mistake in my regex?

Comment: I don't know anything about gulp, but your regex can be broken if `/*` is present inside a string or regex literal, and with ES6 probably also inside a string template.

Comment: working after including spaces. `/\/\*(.|\n|\s|\S)*?\*\//g`

Comment: May I suggest `[\s\S]*?` instead of `(.|\n|\s|\S)*?`? But your regex is still vulnerable, and while it might be possible to fix that, it will be extremely tricky make the regex huge. The problem is that you would need to ignore `/*` if preceded by an uneven number of `'`, `"`, `\`` or `/`, but not counting those that are themselves inside one of those literals too. I mean, try parsing something like `["/*"+'/*'+"'"/*"'"*/,/"'\/*'"/,\`/"'\/*'"/\`,'*/',/*/"'\/*'"/*/'*/']` correctly. Regex is not for parsing, and [you shouldn't use it for that](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/113243).